# Powershell tries to run file in different folder

Tags: powershell

I try to run my script:

```
PS C:\Users\myusernam\myfolder> .\file_name.ps1
```

And i get this response:

```
&: The term 'C:\scripts\file_name.ps1' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: The syntax `.\file_name.ps1` is correct, assuming that a file "file_name.ps1" exists in the current directory. The `&` at the beginning of the error message may indicate that the root of the problem is actually somewhere in your script, perhaps by somehow referring to the current script name. Do you use the call operator `&` in your script?

Comment: omg thank you. I was so fixated on the output in powershell i did not even look into the script. yes the script starts another script that is noth at the right location atm. Put it as an answer and i can accept it.

Comment: I'm still wondering how the current script name ended up in the error message. Would you like to include the relevant part of the script in the question to make this Q&A more useful for others with similar issues?